# Can key cache objects be moved on off-heap memory?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

From page 11 of the [slide](https://www.slideshare.net/DataStax/lessons-learned-on-java-tuning-for-our-cassandra-clusters-carlos-monroy-knewton-c-summit-2016), memtable_allocation_type Cassandra allows to keeping memtables and key cache objects in the native memory, instead of the Java JVM heap. But I found no other evidence that memtable_allocation_type can change the position of key cache.

I'm using apache-cassandra 3.11.3, and are suffering from low key cache hit rate. As increasing key cache size would lead to long gc, is there any way to move key cache to offheap memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, right now the key cache is still in the heap.

I wouldn't say that increase from 1/20th (or 100Mb) to something higher, like 200-300Mb will dramatically increase the garbage collection times...